# By considering expressions of the form $Y(t) = e^{tw}V$, find the general solution to $\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} = AY$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

By considering expressions of the form $Y(t) = e^{tw}V$, find the general solution to $\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} = AY$.

We were given a matrix: $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & -1 & -1  \\
    -1       & 2 & -1  \\
    -1       & -1 & 2 &
\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are 3 and 0.  The corresponding eigenvectors I found are:

For $\lambda = 3$: $$\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           -1 
         \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
          0 \\
          1 \\
           -1 
         \end{bmatrix}. $$
For $\lambda = 0$: $$\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1\\
           1 
         \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I find the general solution?

Thank you!

P.S. $V$ is the eigenvectors.

Comment: I think it would be something like $$Y=A\cdot e^{t\sqrt3}V_{\lambda=3\text{ (first one)}}+B\cdot e^{t\sqrt3}V_{\lambda=3\text{ (second one)}}+C\cdot V_{\lambda=0}$$but that has 3 constants, so I am not sure exactly why that's wrong (hence why I am not putting it as an answer). Perhaps someone can correct it

Answer (score 1):

Plug $Y(t)$ into the differential equation. You'll get $w^2e^{tw}V=Ae^{tw}V$, which can be rewritten as

$$e^{tw}(A-w^2I)V=0.$$

It follows that $w^2=\lambda$ and $V$ is the corresponding eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: But how does this allow for a general solution to be written? As a linear combination of the three factors? If so, wouldn't this have 3 arbitrary constants?

Comment: I think I see where you are going, but how does this lead to a general solution/

Comment: @M.Byrne: See John Doe's comment under your question.

Comment: @AlexR. ahh OK this makes sense.